# Angular Reactive forms form array submit for each element

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a dynamic form where I can add more elements.

```
<form [formGroup]="_formWorkout">
    <div *ngIf="_id>0">
        <!--workouts-->
        <div formArrayName="workouts">
          <div *ngFor="let workout of _formWorkout.controls.workouts.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <span>Workout {{i + 1}}</span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="_formWorkout.controls.workouts.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeWorkout(i)">x</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>name {{workout |json}}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
                <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldInvalid(_formWorkout,['workouts', i, 'name'],'required')"
                  errorMsg="Field is required"></app-field-error-display>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description">
                <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldInvalid(_formWorkout,['workouts', i, 'description'],'required')"
                  errorMsg="Field is required"></app-field-error-display>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <a (click)="kempe(workout)" style="cursor: default">
                      Save
                    </a>
                    <button (click)="kempe(workout)" class="btn btn-primary">{{_submitButtonText}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-20">
          <a (click)="addWorkout()" style="cursor: default">
            Add another workout +
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

This is form in component:

```
this._formWorkout = this._formBuilderWorkout.group({
    workouts: this._formBuilder.array([
    ])
});
```

I don't have luck accessing workout element inside of *ngFor and the way to pass model workout to kempe function.

I want to save workout element for each. As you can see how can I pass each element for itself to api instead of all collection:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can access your array by using  get method, then the FormArray method at to access it

i.e.

```
control = <FormArray>this.formWorkout.get('workouts')
console.log(contol.at(0));
```

or quicker

```
console.log( (<FormArray>this.formWorkout.get('workouts')).at(0));
```

and if you want just the value, and not the form group

```
console.log( (<FormArray>this.formWorkout.get('workouts')).at(0).value);
```

Regarding your reactive form, I prefer to use the FormGroup, FormArray and FormControl constructor to know exactly where I'm assigning what, but this will help you get going

.component

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formWorkout" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="workouts">
    <div
            *ngFor="let workout of formWorkout.get('workouts').controls;  let i=index"
            class="panel panel-default"
            [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span>Workout {{i + 1}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <!--<label>name {{workout |json}}</label>-->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>description</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="removeWorkout(i)">
        x
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="indexSelected=i" type="submit" style="cursor: default">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="margin-20">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="addWorkout()" style="cursor: default">
      Add another workout +
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**.ts**

```
formWorkout: FormGroup;
indexSelected = 0;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

    // Create our form group, and feed it the form control,
    // in this case just a workout array
    this.formWorkout = new FormGroup( {
      'workouts' : new FormArray([
        // Instantiate one
        new FormGroup({
          'name': new FormControl(''),
          'description': new FormControl('')
        })
      ])
    });

  }

  addWorkout() {
    (<FormArray>this.formWorkout.get('workouts')).push(
      new FormGroup({
        'name': new FormControl(''),
        'description': new FormControl(''),
      })
    )
  }

  removeWorkout(index: number) {
    (<FormArray>this.formWorkout.get('workouts')).removeAt(index);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log( (<FormArray>this.formWorkout.get('workouts')).at(this.indexSelected).value);
  }
```

If you feed submit here an index argument, it should be able to give you enough information so you can index the form group array and get the corresponding values

Comment: bro this wont work. this only has one save button, i need multiple saves for each element. i already figured it out, ill post answer later.

Comment: amels can you post answer